# how to listen for clicks in Java (JFreeChart) using events?

Tags: java, jfreechart, addeventlistener

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("detectado");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`addChartMouseListener()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#addChartMouseListener%28org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener%29) to add a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) to your `ChartPanel`. For example, in [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.62), add the following:

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getEntity());
    }

    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen for clicks, you must check the type of event.

In particular, you override the

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev)
```

method, which is part of the interface for MouseListeners.

For a fill example see : [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/Rightclicktotriggerthepopupmenu.htm)

Comment: sorry im new and tried to copy all the code (it's not that much) but i could'nt 

problem is it doesn't detect anything, i overrided but nothing happens, more ideas? (thx so much for the patience)