# Selecting a curve in jFreechart

Tags: java, selection, jfreechart

I have several time series plotted with jfreechart. The graph also contains multiple annotations. I want the user to be able to select the time series or the annotations.

So far I have tried: `entityCollection.getEntity(x,y)` which returns me the `PlotEntity` and `panel.getComponentAt(x,y)` which gives me the chart panel.

so my question is: can jFreechart provide me with this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `ChartMouseListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219445/230513). The `ChartMouseEvent` will indicate which `ChartEntity` subclass was found.

Comment: Since I also plan to implement mouseDragged I can't use it directly, but using your pointer I could find my mistake quickly. Problem was I had to correct the mouse coordinates - and I found the code in ChartPanel.java