# Accessing Legend Item text

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating a Bar Chart:

```
final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createBarChart(TITLE, // chart title
    X_TITLE, // domain axis label
    Y_TITLE, // range axis label
    dataset, // data
    PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, // the plot orientation
    true, // legend
    true, // tooltips
    false // urls
    );
```

I then added a ChartMouseListener as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218853/how-to-listen-for-clicks-in-java-jfreechart-using-events/8219445#8219445).

When I click on a legend item, "LegendItemEntity: seriesKey=null, dataset=null" is displayed.

How do I access the legend text for the corresponding item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from [`org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java) and adding the same `ChartMouseListener` to the [source](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/ad2112371b403721f922c2b34938d61653c16f0a/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java#L60) yields results like this:

```
LegendItemEntity: seriesKey=First, dataset=org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset@d9510071
LegendItemEntity: seriesKey=Second, dataset=org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset@d9510071
LegendItemEntity: seriesKey=Third, dataset=org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset@d9510071
```

If you're geting a different result, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may help.