# Show different Labels on the axis as opposed to what the chartEntity returns for a plotted JFreeChart's chart

Tags: mouseevent, jfreechart, bar-chart

I have overridden the chartMouseClicked () method to capture the ChartMouseEvent for my barChart. I want to get the dataset when the mouse is clicked on one of the bars. However the event should not respond when clicked anywhere else on the chartpanel. How can I filter this.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the erroneous close; I was reading the old question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to examine the [`ChartEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/ChartEntity.html) returned by [`ChartMouseEvent#getEntity()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseEvent.html#getEntity%28%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219445/230513).