# Overlay button on top of JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jfreechart

I am new to JFreechart and having a play with the different features provided.
I am looking at an option to overlay a JButton on top of Jfreechart.
For eg:- I have a chart with time/price and at some points in the graph, I want to have an option to have a button so that I can retrieve more details. 
Even a custom tooltip would help, but having a button would give more flexibility.

Is this something that can be done using JFreeChart?

Answer (score 1):

To see what `ChartEntity` is under the mouse, you can add a `ChartMouseListener` to your `ChartPanel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219445/230513).

Comment: Thanks, but is there a possibility of adding a button inside the chart at specific points so that the button is over the chart?

Comment: I've never tried. You could change the layout in `ChartPanel` and `add()` the button, but I'd just put it in a nearby container.

Comment: The reason for the button(very small one) is I want to highlight the points which has additional details, so when I click the button I can display more information. This would allow me to attract attention to specific points in the chart instead of moving the cursor all over the chart.

Comment: I'd use an annotation for that; see also [`OverlayLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).