# Drawing Line chart in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I want to draw a graph on each point of which there will be a button. When I will click the button, it will do something. Here's a [link](http://codeforces.com/profile/tourist); I want my graph to look like this. Can anybody suggest me how to do it?

Comment: *"Can anybody suggest me how to do it?"*  See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for details.  This is 'too broad' to be covered on SO.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI i have found a way to draw the graph but how to add the buttons.can you tell me @AndrewThompson

Comment: First, I wouldn't use actual `JButton` objects, but instead draw them using Java 2D.  Then add a `MouseMotionListener` and a `MouseListener` to the component drawing the graph and check for clicks using the `MouseListener` and the pointer entering/leaving the `Shape` that comprises each 'button' using the other listener.  If you get stuck, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of your attempt along with a *specific* question.

Comment: Consider something like JFreeCharts

Answer (score 1):

Using [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info), add a `ChartMouseListener` to your `ChartPanel`, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219445/230513). In your implementation of `chartMouseClicked()` invoke  `Desktop#browse()`, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967469/230513). In outline,

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
        // construct a URI based the result from e.getEntity()
        desktop.browse(uri);
    }

    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {}

});
```