# Adding button on jfreechart in java

Tags: java, user-interface, jfreechart

I have a graph like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo6.htm) . I want to add button on each point of the graph like in (1,1) , (2,4) and so on. I want do different thing when i click on this button.How can i do it?

Comment: Please don't keep repeating the same question; instead, edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192514/drawing-line-chart-in-java) to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits any problem you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should provide some code of your existing project, it is much easier to help you!

I am not completely sure about this code, but pls give it a try:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(...);
chart.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Click event!");
            if(e.getChartEntity != null){
                System.out.println("clicked directly on the chart");
            }
        }
        });
```

regards 
me

Comment: i will use the same code of this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo6.htm) your code works but it works for the whole panel but what i want is to click on specific point and do specific things like the graph in [this](http://codeforces.com/profile/tourist) link.

Comment: Hey. Oh I am sorry that my answer wasn't correct. I only had the documentation on hand but couldn't try it myself. But I'm glad you worked it out.